# Is there a way to find a last substring?

Tags: mysql, search, substring

my brain might be really tired but i coudn't seem to work my head around this simple query.. I want to extract a last substring within delimiters such as ',' from a column? i was thinking about using REVERSE or RIGHT.. but the results are coming off as really bizarre...

Lets say i have a table column 'DESCRIPTION' in a table LOANS with an entry

```
Changed Loan Laptop from "IT-X130E-10" to "IT-X130E-9".
```

and i want the last substring

```
IT-X130E-9
```

within delimiters '"' hope its clearer now

Comment: please give sample records.

Comment: Without sample records as @JW웃 suggested, all I can say is to look at `SUBSTR()` and `LOCATE()`

Comment: lets say i want to extract IT-X130E-10 from 'Changed Loan Laptop from "IT-X130E-10" to "IT-X130E-9"'.

Comment: Still rather confused... Update your post using markdown to separate things to make it less confusing.

Comment: @Nile he wants to find the key with the highest ID, as depicted by the number at the end. In this case, 9 is less than 10, so it returns the name with the ID of 10.

Comment: @DaftPunk hmmm... Are you sure it's the highest ID and not just the first ID?

Comment: @Nile read the comment he made. He seems to want to parse the one with the highest value at the end.

Comment: @DaftPunk Actually, in the comment he said he wanted to extract the "10", but in his OP he said he wants to extract "the last substring"

Comment: If you're using REVERSE, remember to also reverse the string you're querying with. That might explain why the results are "weird", hard to tell from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try [SUBSTRING INDEX(str,delim,count)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('yourString', '"', -2), '"', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is `reverse()` and some brute force:

```
select replace(replace(right(val, instr(substring(reverse(val), 3, 100), '"')+2), '"', ''), '.', '')
from (select 'Changed Loan Laptop from "IT-X130E-10" to "IT-X130E-9".' as val) t
```

This assumes that the string does not contain either `'"'` or `'.'`.

Comment: Thanks but some entries do have full stop within them.